# MVC - windows authentication using local computer accounts and groups

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an mvc application set up to use windows authentication. I also have a development environment which I sometimes work offline.

I want to keep the existing windows authentication when working offline. I was thinking of creating local users and groups when working offline. However, I cannot get this working. I am receiving an error that the trust relationship failed.

Is it possible to use this approach in MVC (i.e. Windows authetnication using the local computer groups and not a domain controller)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on what you authorizes against: If you authorize using kerberos against a domain controller, than no, your local approach won't woprk because you simply are no domain controller. Your OS needs to provides any services your app uses or your app needs to use what your offline OS provides, simple as that. You may implement or configure or whatever local authentication for your app in case you are offline, depends on what exactly you use for authorization.

Comment: I am setting the authentication mode to Windows. Does this imply kerberos + DC? I had assumed that this would also work with local accounts but it does not seem to be the case.

Comment: How do you specify the allowed users? Do they contain a domainname and if so, which? From my understanding the name of your local machine should be the domainname, if that doesn't work and gets forwarded to a non existing domain controller, that may be the default behavior if your machine is part of a domain. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323176/en-us

Comment: Thanks - just helped me out to figure out the problem. I was not using the computer name but BUILTIN\groupname. It worked correctly once I used the computer name instead of BUILTIN. Thanks again!